# How to show downshift + popper on top of material-ui dialog?

Tags: material-ui

I've implemented an autocomplete multi-select field based on the `Downshift` with `Popper` [Material-UI demo](https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/#downshift). That worked well up until I tried to reuse the component within a [Material-UI Dialog](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/#dialog). The `Popper` appears behind the mask of the `Dialog`.

[image: Popper behind dialog's mask]

I've modified the Material-UI demo as an example of this behavior: https://codesandbox.io/s/76moj1mq1.

Looking at Material-UI's old auto-complete solution, it use to use `Popover` instead of `Popper`. I tried substituting that in to see if it's `z-index` would be higher than that of the `Dialog`, but I think `Popover` steals focus from `Downshift` in a way that triggers the autocomplete to close immediately after it opens. Here's an example, again modifying Material-UI's demo https://codesandbox.io/s/wk84p1myz7.

Any ideas on how I can make either approach work?

Answer (score 12):

Overriding `z-index` on the `Popper` to be above the 1300 that [Material-UI defaults](https://material-ui.com/layout/basics/#z-index) dialogs to works, but I was hoping to avoid having to do that if possible.

Comment: Did you create issue on @material-ui github repository?